# Treat functions by name

Tags: c, linux, function, function-pointers

Suppose you created a `main()` to deal with an exercise you asked your students.

Every student is supposed to write their own function, with the same API. And a single file will be created, with all functions and the main calling them.

Lets say: `int studentname(int a, int b)` is the function pattern.

One way I deal with it was using a vector of pointer to functions `int (*func[MAX])()`. But you need to fulfill the vector one by one `func[0]=studentname;`.

I wonder, is there a way a function can be called by its name somehow?

Something like: `int student1(int a , int b)`, `student2()`, etc.

And in `main` somehow we could just call `sscanf(funcname,"student%d",i); funcname();`.

Do you have any other idea? Maybe

```
int studentname(int a, int b, char *fname)
{
    strcpy(fname, "studentname");
```

Anything creative will do! :)

Thanks!
Beco

PS. I tried just a vector of functions, but C won't allow me! :)

`int func[2]()={{;},{;}};`

This way I could just give to each student a number, and voilá... But no way. It was funny though.

---

Edited: I'm using linux.

Edited 2: Thanks! I've accepted an answer that helped me, but I've also documented a complete example as an answer bellow.

Comment: Generate the code? Some script to read your list of names, convert to correct format (e.g. all lowercase, all spaces and special chars removed) and just dump the call.

Comment: A minimal example would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen
Example of cosine:
` *(void **) (&cosine) = dlsym(handle, "cos");`

I think that is the call, isn't it?

Comment: Something just occurred to me: what is the outcome of the student's function? Perhaps it's better to compile each student's code into executable which prints the result to standard out, and make a script (whatever language) which fork/exec-s each of the binaries, parses the output and validates/compares it? It has a lot of advantages (separation, possibility to kill process looping forever, etc.).

Comment: I've teaching and using this schema for a lot of exercices with different outcome. Specifically for the current exercise, its a sequence of choices, and each function should return an int that represents a choice. The combined choices leads to a path of possibilities, and new choices must be made. :) So, being simple an int, its better to get the number than parse the answer from stdout. But I agree, for other exercises, that could be a nice elegant solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe a bit overcomplicating it, but spontaneous idea:

- Compile all student source files into one shared library with the students' functions being exports.
- Then enumerate all exposed functions, call and test them.

As an alternative:

- Write a small tool that will compile all "student units" using a preprocessor define to replace a predefined function name with an unique name ("func1", "func2", etc.).
- Then let the tool write a small unit calling all these functions while performing tests, etc.

And yet another idea:

- Use C++ to write a special class template that's going to register derived classes in a object factory and just embed student's code using `extern "C"`. Depending on the implementation this might look a bit confusing and overcomplicated though.
- Then use the factory to create one instance of each and run the code.

---

Example for the approach with `dlopen()` and `dlsym()` (whether only one function per library or all - doesn't matter):

```
void *pluginlib = dlopen("student1.so", RTLD_NOW); // RTLD_NOW will load the file right away
if (!pluginlib)
    ; // failed to load
studentproc func = (studentproc)dlsym(pluginlib, "student1"); // this loads the function called "student1"
if (!func)
    ; // failed to resolve
func("hello world!"); // call the lib
dlclose(pluginlib); // unloads the dll (this will make all further calls invalid)
```

Comment: Before posting the question I was thinking about preprocessor. But I couldn't see a way out.

Comment: It wouldn't be preprocessor only. Just a tool using the preprocessor for quick renaming/editing without actually touching the files.

Comment: How exactly would you do item 2: enumerate exposed functions and call them? I think that is my main doubt here, and it seems to be a good solution if possible. Is it with dlopen and dlsym, also suggested by others?

Comment: Added a short example for `dlopen()`/`dlsym()`. I'm not really sure how to enumerate all functions in one file, sorry. :)

Comment: Thanks! Very useful. I'll add a minimal example to show the solution. But you deserve the accepted answer for that!

Answer (score 2):

Similar to what @Jamey-Sharp proposed:

- ask each student to provide `.c` file with entry function of a given name/signature
- compile each `.c` into a shared library, named by the student name, or given whatever unique name. This step can be easily automated with `make` or simple script.
- make a simple host application which enumerates all `.so` files in a given directory, and uses `dlopen()` and `dlsym()` to get to the entry point function.
- now you can simply call each student's implementation.

BTW, that's how plug-ins are implemented usually, isn't it?

**Edit:** Here's a working proof of concept (and a proof, that each student can use the same name of the entry point function).

Here's `student1.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void student_task()
{
    printf("Hello, I'm Student #1\n");    
}
```

Here's `student2.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void student_task()
{
    printf("Hello, I'm Student #2\n");    
}
```

And here's the main program, `tester.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

/* NOTE: Error handling intentionally skipped for brevity! 
 * It's not a production code!
 */

/* Type of the entry point function implemented by students */
typedef void (*entry_point_t)(void);

/* For each student we have to store... */
typedef struct student_lib_tag {
    /* .. pointer to the entry point function, */
    entry_point_t entry;
    /* and a library handle, so we can play nice and close it eventually */ 
    void* library_handle;
} student_solution_t;

void load(const char* lib_name, student_solution_t* solution)
{
    /* Again - all error handling skipped, I only want to show the idea! */

    /* Open the library. RTLD_LOCAL is quite important, it keeps the libs separated */
    solution->library_handle = dlopen(lib_name, RTLD_NOW | RTLD_LOCAL);

    /* Now we ask for 'student_task' function. Every student uses the same name.
     * strange void** is needed for C99, see dlsym() manual.
     */
    *(void**) (&solution->entry) = dlsym(solution->library_handle, "student_task");

    /* We have to keep the library open */
}

int main()
{
    /* Two entries hardcoded - you need some code here that would scan
     * the directory for .so files, allocate array dynamically and load 
     * them all.
     */
    student_solution_t solutions[2];

    /* Load both solutions */
    load("./student1.so", &solutions[0]);
    load("./student2.so", &solutions[1]);

    /* Now we can call them both, despite the same name of the entry point function! */
    (solutions[0].entry)();
    (solutions[1].entry)();

    /* Eventually it's safe to close the libs */
    dlclose(solutions[0].library_handle);
    dlclose(solutions[1].library_handle);
    return 0;
}
```

Let's compile it all:

```
czajnik@czajnik:~/test$ gcc -shared -fPIC student1.c -o student1.so -Wall
czajnik@czajnik:~/test$ gcc -shared -fPIC student2.c -o student2.so -Wall
czajnik@czajnik:~/test$ gcc tester.c -g -O0 -o tester -ldl  -Wall
```

And see it works:

```
czajnik@czajnik:~/test$ ./tester 
Hello, I'm Student #1
Hello, I'm Student #2
```

Comment: Looks like dlsym and dlopen is the way to go. I'm just a little confused on how to use them, as I never used them before. I'll read more of the documentation if I can't find a minimum example that works at all.

Comment: It's pretty straightforward. Only did it on Windows, but on Unix it's probably rather similar: With `dlopen()` you load the library which will return a handle. Then you use the handle together with `dlsym()` to obtain the address of a given function. Just cast it to the apropriate signature and you're done. And yes, that's essentially how plugins are usually done.

Comment: I'd say it's rather easy (and fun!) - `dlsym()` man page contains a simple example, see http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlsym

Comment: But I need to write the name to `dlsym()`? Like

`funcs[i] = dlsym(handle, funcname);` And I use sscanf to put funcname together like in the question?

Comment: Yes, you need to give `dlsym()` the function name. But it can be the same name for each student's file, you won't get any name clash loading it via `dlopen()`/`dlsym()`.

Comment: It doesn't matter! Using `dlsym()` you can import multiple functions of the same name, from separate libraries. Unfortunately I had no chance to show any example yesterday (I have to sleep sometimes ;) - but let me do it now. I'll update my answer in a few minutes.

Comment: That's a good solution. Thanks! People who google to here should definitely take some time to understand the concepts used in that.

Answer (score 1):

I'd take a different approach:

1. Require every student to use the same function name, and place each student's code in a separate source file.
2. Write one more source file with a `main` that calls the standard name.
3. Produce a separate executable from linking `main.c` with `student1.c`, then `main.c` with `student2.c`, and so on. You might be able to use wildcards in a makefile or shell script to automate this.

That said, at least on Unix-like OSes, you **can** do what you asked for.

1. Call `dlopen(NULL)` to get a handle on the symbols in the main program.
2. Pass that handle and the function name you want to `dlsym`. Coerce the resulting pointer to a function pointer of the right type, and call it.

Comment: That won't do, because main need to call a combination of students and oppose results.

Comment: Hmmm, that wasn't in your specification. :-)

Comment: Sorry about that. But I also didn't say I would call only one at time! :P

Comment: I'm reading about dlopen and dlsym. Sounds promising. I never used it, so I'm having a hard time to figure them out.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an ugly preprocessor hack:

```
#Makefile

FILE_NAME=student

${FILE_NAME}: main.c
        cc -Wall -DFILE_NAME=\"${FILE_NAME}.c\" -o $@ main.c -lm
```

Teacher's main.c:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include FILE_NAME

char *my_name(void);
double my_sin(double val);

int main(void)
{
double dd;
dd = my_sin(3.1415923563);

printf("%s: %f\n", my_name(), dd);
return 0;
}
```

Student's .c File:

```
#include <math.h>

char * my_name(void);
double my_sin(double val);

char * my_name(void)
{
return "Wildplasser-1.0";
}

double my_sin(double val)
{
return sin (val);
}
```

The trick lies i the literal inclusion of the student's .c file.

To avoid this, you could also use a different make line, like:

```
 cc -Wall -o $@ ${FILE_NAME}.c main.c -lm
```

(and remove the ugly `#include FILENAME`, of course)

Comment: This doesn't work because I may need to call more than one student's function at a time, to hot compare results. But thanks! Nice catch.

Comment: Hot compare: redirect stdout, and use plain ordinary diff (or a database) Since you supply the main() routine, you can instrument it at your will.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks you all. I've accepted an answer that gave me the inspiration to solve the question. Here, just to document it, is my complete solution:

File shamain.c

```
/* Uses shared library shalib.so
 * Compile with:
 *    gcc shamain.c -o shamain -ldl -Wall
 */


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main(void)
{
  void *libstud;
  int (*student[2])(int, int);
  char fname[32];
  int i,r;

  libstud = dlopen("./shalib.so", RTLD_NOW);
  if (!libstud)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "error: %s\n", dlerror());
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  dlerror();    /* Clear any existing error */

  for(i=0; i<2; i++)
  {
    sprintf(fname, "func%d", i);
    *(void **) (&student[i]) = dlsym(libstud, fname); /* c99 crap */
    //student[i] = (int (*)(int, int)) dlsym(libstud, fname); /* c89 format */
  }

  for(i=0; i<2; i++)
  {
    r=student[i](i, i);
    printf("i=%d,r=%d\n", i, r);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

File shalib.c

```
/* Shared library.
 * Compile with:
 *  gcc -shared -fPIC shalib.c -o shalib.so -Wall
 */

#include <stdio.h>

int func0(int one, int jadv)
{
  printf("%d = Smith\n", one);
  return 0;
}

int func1(int one, int jadv)
{
  printf("%d = John\n", one);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ah, okay, skipping enumerating is another idea. :) Just to add: don't pass a file name to `dlopen()` allows you to get functions within the executable - so you don't even need the library.

Comment: Will I use `libstud = dlopen(NULL, RTLD_NOW);` ?
Would I get functions from `shamain.c`?

Comment: Yes, that will make it check your executable's symbol table for the functions. Not only shamain.c but any object file/translation unit linked into your executable.

Answer (score 0):

It is a while since I have used shared libraries, but I have a feeling you can extract named functions from a DLL/shlib. Could you create a DLL/shared library containing all of the implementations and then access them by name from the main?

Comment: Oh, I should add, I'm using linux. But I believe your comment is platform free... Regarding it, well, I don't see exactly how.

Answer (score 0):

Per @william-morris's suggestion, you might have luck using `dlsym()` to do a dynamic lookup of the functions. (`dlsym()` may or may not be the library call to use on your particular platform.)